# How to add a textfield in form with out model class in YII?

Tags: php, yii

I need to add a text field in YII form in which i am not specify any model class name. But I need to process that value in the action method inside the controller class.

ie

I need to add a text field as

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" name="test" id="test" >
</div>
```

I add text field as

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model['groupModel'],'group_name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
```

But i do't want to specify any model name with the new text field..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this in the view? Whats stopping you from adding it in the hold fashion way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a [Chtml textfield](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#textField-detail) with an id

It will the show in the: $_POST['mytextField']

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am new to YII. I used the code as 
<div class="row">
                <?php echo CHtml::textField("testvalue");?>
        </div>
When i use
var_dump($_POST['User']);
inside the action method in controller it is not contain the text field value..

Answer (score 7):

This should work

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::textField('User[textvalue]', '', array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>                
</div>
```

This will give you the text value inside $_POST['User'] as $_POST['User']['textvalue']