# Exception (Unknown Property) 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Getting unknown property: app\models\User::repeat_password'

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I am new in Yii framework. This is my first post in stackoverflow for related framework. My problem is how to show non model input field in the view page. Please check my controler and view code.

#### controllers

```
public function actionRegister() {
    $model = new User();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        //Insert data code here...
        return $this->render('entry-confirm', ['model' => $model]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('entry', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

#### views(entry.php)

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'repeat_password')->passwordInput() ?>

<div class="form-group">
<?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

#### models(User.php)

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

    public static function tableName() {
        return 'user';
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['username', 'password', 'email'], 'required'],
            [['username', 'password', 'email'], 'string', 'max' => 128],
            ['email', 'email', 'message' => "The email isn't correct"],
            ['email', 'unique', 'message' => 'Email already exists!'],

            ['repeat_password', 'required'],
            [['repeat_password'], 'string', 'min'=>6, 'max'=>40],
            ['password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'repeat_password'],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels() {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'email' => 'Email',
        ];
    }

}
```

#### Output

[image]

I have 3 column in my `user` table. Columns are `username`, `email` and `password` but `repeat_password` is not in my table column. This is a non model input field. So I am getting above error message. Please help me and let me know how to fix it.

Comment: update your question add  you related  model

Comment: @scaisEdge I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add new public property to `User.php` (model class file) as

```
class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $repeat_password;
```

Please refer to this first

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-forms.html

It will not take much time.

Don't forget to add its validation rules  in `rules` method of `User.php`
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#safe-attributes

Comment: I don't think that is good idea. This field doesn't have to be in database/model so

Comment: @AlexSlipknot Whats your preferred way?

Comment: It can be just some post variable.

Comment: Then how will you validate it?

Comment: See answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104388/how-to-add-a-textfield-in-form-with-out-model-class-in-yii

Comment: validation must be in controller with **$app->request->post()**

Comment: Still there is no way to validate it. It will just POST to the controller then all validation we have to do manually. I think this is not a good idea

Comment: What? Validation executing in controller in his case. There are all needed data to validate it

Comment: But validation rules must be in model rather than controller

Comment: Yes, it is. In validation method of model you just can receive post data without applying model attributes

Comment: @SohelAhmedM thank you for your answering. I just add `public $repeat_password;` now everything working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related  to the fact you are using a

```
  <?= $form->field($model, 'repeat_password') ?>
```

that not exist for the User Model ..

you should create a a FormModel (eg: UserInput with also this `repeat_password` field  )  for manage the correct input and then in action mange properly the assigment from your formModel/UserInput model and User model   for store

for build a proper form model class you can take a looka at this  guide  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-forms.html

Comment: I am not getting your point. Can you explain me about your answer.

Comment: @Chinmay235   sure  .. the message error is realeted  to the fact you have not a field name repeat_password  in the model you are using in view  (User model don't have the repeat_password )  .. the you can resolve this using a model specifically for manage this situation  .. you can create a FormModel  .. alias   model non based on ActiveRecord .. than contain the fileld you need  (the field for User and the msissing repeat_password  ) .. you then should create and pass to view this FormModel and get the resull fo input by submit .. ,,let me know if this is clear  ..