# Yii2: I have a new column and now I get Getting unknown property

Tags: gridview, yii2, dataprovider

I have a find function in my **CarsSearch model**:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Cars::find()->select(['color' => '1']); // This is a longer SQL query.

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        $query  => $query,
        $this->load($params);
        return $dataProvider;
    ]);
}
```

I use that $dataProvider in my very simple **cars view**:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'color'
    ]
]) ?>
```

But I got this error:

```
Getting unknown property: app\models\Cars::color
```

How can I add the **color** property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that property `color` is in your database table `cars`, so your class `Cars` must be extended by `ActiveRecord`. You have to just add `color` in rules of your model `Cars`. For example:

```
['color', 'integer']
```

The way you added it, the property will be always `null` except you set some value. If you set it in rules, when you find object, the object will have `color` with value that is in your database.
If you have some questions, give your code from class `Cars` and `CarsSearch`

Answer (score 1):

I added in my **cars model** as I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140365/exception-unknown-property-yii-base-unknownpropertyexception-with-message-g) and it works:

```
public $color;
```

Comment: If you use it like this then It will not point to your db column, It is just object property and value is related to object only.